# Resize images to a thumbnail version

Tags: javascript

I have an array of standard photos I want user to be able to choose for a background photo.  I am unsure how to resize these photos.  I need the aspect ratio to stay the same and the width to be `400px`.  And I want to resave them with `- thumbnail` at the end of their filename.

IMAGES FROM CONTROLLER

```
$scope.standardPhotos = [
  "/images/app-directory-images/default1.png",
  "/images/app-directory-images/default2.png",
  "/images/app-directory-images/default3.png",
  "/images/app-directory-images/default4.png",
  "/images/app-directory-images/default5.png"
];
```

Comment: You can use the canvas element to resize these images - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the canvas, though that uses a really bad algorithm to downsample. I went to use an MIT-licensed [Hermite downsampler](https://github.com/viliusle/Hermite-resize/blob/master/hermite.js) instead in the end, which also works utilizing a canvas, but is not as bad as the default resizer.

Note that resampling pictures is a computation-resource-heavy operation when done right, so it is highly preferred to just resize them beforehand in any image-editor of your choice (or even a [web-app](https://pixlr.com/)) and upload those to your server, to prevent every user from doing these calculations every time.

Saving files is always limited by browser restrictions and all you can do is ask the user whether he or she wants to save the file. If you meant that the user sends the resized image back to the server to save it, pay extra attention to security and do not assume the data comes from your javascript on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more information about what you are using?